# I am having a problem running a query on SQL using bigquery and it doesn't display any data

Tags: sql, database, join, google-bigquery, inner-join

```
SELECT
 'Second_dataset.Employees.name' AS Employees_name,
 'Second_dataset.Employees.role' AS Employees_name,
 'Second_dataset.Departments.department_id' AS department_name
FROM
 `Second_dataset.Employees`
INNER JOIN
 `Second_dataset.Departments`
ON
 'Second_dataset.Employees.department_id' = 'Second_dataset_Departments.department_id'
```

Every time i run the query there is no data displayed i have checked the names of the columns and they are correct does anyone know how I can solve this problem

I was expecting this as shown in the google data analytics professional certificate course :

[image]

but i keep getting no data displayed

This is the Departments Table:

[image]

This is the Employees Table :

[image]

Comment: Probably the dot was accidentally replaced with underscore here: Second_dataset_Departments.department_id. Strange you don't see any error messages though.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has multiple issues. Most visible is using apostrophes where it should be back-ticks
Try below instead

```
SELECT
 e.name AS Employees_name,
 e.role AS Employees_name,
 d.department_id AS department_name
FROM
 `Second_dataset.Employees` e
INNER JOIN
 `Second_dataset.Departments` d
ON
 e.department_id = d.department_id
```